# How to detect / prevent systemd network startup failures

Tags: centos, networking, boot, systemd

Using Centos 7 (most recent updates), on a remote firewall machine that is 200 miles away, I have occasional difficulty on reboot with the network stack not properly starting up.  The box has 3 interfaces, and usually the external DHCP interface takes just a little longer to come up, and the network stack isn't waiting correctly, the result is a server that started up but unreachable via the internet.

The network card is a dual Intel chipset using the e1000e driver.  I had this problem much worse with the onboard interface, so I got this card to fix the problem.  It helped, but still not perfectly solved.  Most times another soft reboot or restart of the network stack brings it back online correctly.

I'm using the legacy network scripts, not NetworkManager because of the interface complexity and needing good remote setup; I frequently struggle to get NM to correctly start up complex configurations.

Even considering some type of emergency network monitor that would attempt to restart/reboot if it sees the network is not online.  When it fails, I have to coach my 85 yr old mother in basic Linux networking commands, which I'm sure you can all appreciate is a challenge.

Here is the /var/log/messages of the most recent boot failure.

```
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: Bringing up loopback interface:  Cannot get current device settings: No such device
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting speed
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting duplex
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting autoneg
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: [  OK  ]
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: Bringing up interface enp1s0f0:  Cannot get current device settings: No such device
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting speed
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting duplex
May 14 04:58:55 windward network: not setting autoneg
May 14 04:58:55 windward kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0f0: link is not ready
May 14 04:59:00 windward kernel: e1000e: enp1s0f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
May 14 04:59:00 windward kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0f0: link becomes ready
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: Determining IP information for enp1s0f0... failed; no link present.  Check cable?
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: [FAILED]
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: Bringing up interface enp1s0f1:  Cannot get current device settings: No such device
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: not setting speed
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: not setting duplex
May 14 04:59:01 windward network: not setting autoneg
May 14 04:59:01 windward kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0f1: link is not ready
May 14 04:59:03 windward kernel: e1000e: enp1s0f1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
May 14 04:59:03 windward kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0f1: link becomes ready
May 14 04:59:04 windward network: Determining if ip address 10.20.128.1 is already in use for device enp1s0f1...
May 14 04:59:06 windward network: [  OK  ]
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: Unit network.service entered failed state.
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: network.service failed.
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: Reached target Network.
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: Starting Network.
May 14 04:59:06 windward systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ip link show`?

Comment: What network device is the computer connected to? When Ethernet links are slow to come up, a common cause is a switch that doesn't have portfast enabled on that port.

Comment: This port is directly connected to a new fiber device that was recently installed in the house for phone,cable,internet.  I know very little about that device, stuck in an enclosed box outside the house.

But it all seemed to either start or get much worse since that point.

Results of "ip link show" for enp1s0f0:
3: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:6d:35:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Note the IP LINK SHOW lines above are from when the link is up and connected.  Can't say how it would look when the link didn't come up.

Comment: Reading a bit more documentation, would it help if I add 
    LINKDELAY=60
to the interface file?

Current contents of ifcfg-enp1s0f0:
    HWADDR=00:15:17:6D:35:FE
    TYPE=Ethernet
    BOOTPROTO=dhcp
    DEFROUTE=yes
    PEERDNS=yes
    PEERROUTES=yes
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    IPV6INIT=yes
    IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
    IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
    IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
    IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    NAME="Wired connection 1"
    UUID=8f3a2310-2edd-45f6-874d-6d37606f189e
    ONBOOT=yes
    DEVICE=enp1s0f0
    DNS1=127.0.0.1
    DNS2=167.142.225.3

Comment: Yes, try adding the LINKDELAY line.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to increase DHCP client timeout in the config file?

Can you try to edit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and set the 'timeout' option like shown below:

```
timeout=60
```